# SQL Server Conditional Sequence Number

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of customers from a table and I want to assign each a Sequential number and save it to another table.
However, the sequence should restart every month.

Currently, I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO tblSerialNo
SELECT CustomerNo
      ,FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMM')
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerNo ASC) AS SerialNo 
FROM tblCustomer
```

But the sequence on SerialNo column continues even the month has changed.

Current Output:

```
--------------------------
|Customer|Month |SerialNo|
|--------+------+--------|
|17000001|201710|00001   |
|17000002|201710|00002   |
|17000003|201710|00003   |
|17000004|201710|00004   |
|17000005|201710|00005   |
|17000001|201710|00006   |
|17000002|201710|00007   |
|17000003|201710|00008   |
|17000004|201710|00009   |
|17000005|201710|00010   |
|17000001|201711|00011   |
|17000002|201711|00012   |
|17000003|201711|00013   |
|17000004|201711|00014   |
|17000005|201711|00015   |
--------------------------
```

Desired Output:

```
--------------------------
|Customer|Month |SerialNo|
|--------+------+--------|
|17000001|201710|00001   |
|17000002|201710|00002   |
|17000003|201710|00003   |
|17000004|201710|00004   |
|17000005|201710|00005   |
|17000001|201710|00006   |
|17000002|201710|00007   |
|17000003|201710|00008   |
|17000004|201710|00009   |
|17000005|201710|00010   |
|17000001|201711|00001   |
|17000002|201711|00002   |
|17000003|201711|00003   |
|17000004|201711|00004   |
|17000005|201711|00005   |
--------------------------
```

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what does `INSERT INTO tblSerialNo` suppose to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `PARTITION BY` before your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
INSERT INTO tblSerialNo
SELECT CustomerNo
      ,FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMM')
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMM') ORDER BY CustomerNo ASC) AS SerialNo 
FROM tblCustomer
```

Comment: can u explain how `insert` and `select` work together?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
INSERT INTO tblSerialNo
select customerno,[Month],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by [Month] ORDER BY CustomerNo ASC) AS SerialNo  from 
(
SELECT CustomerNo ,FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMM')as [Month] FROM tblCustomer
)as a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblSerialNo
SELECT CustomerNo
      ,FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMM')
      ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By FORMAT(getdate(), 'yyyyMM') Order By CustomerNo ASC)As SerialNo 
FROM tblCustomer
```